# Is there a workaround for the maximum length of an ODBCConnection.CommandText string in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, odbc, command-text

I have a VBA script that generates a query string for a SAP HANA ODBC Connection in Excel. The query is determined by user inputs and can vary greatly in length. The query itself uses many versions of a similar query appended to one another using UNION ALL syntax.

The script sometimes throws a runtime error when trying to refresh. From my research, it has become clear that the reason for this is that the CommandText string exceeds a maximum allowed length of 32,767 (https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/50819/too-long-sql-in-excel-vba.html).

I wondered whether there is a workaround for this, other than using a stored procedure (I am not against this if there is a way to **create a stored procedure at runtime** then execute it, but I cannot use a predefined stored procedure as my query is always different hence the need for VBA to create it)

Some more info about the dynamic query in VBA:

- Column names, as well as parameters, are created dynamically and can be different every time
- The query uses groups of lists of product numbers to generate an IN statement for each product group, then sums the sales for those products under the name of the group. These are then all UNION'd together to create one table with grouped records

Example of user input:

[image: Example of user input]

Example of resulting query:

```sql
WITH SOME_CTE (SOME_FIELDS) AS 
(SELECT SOME_STUFF
FROM SOME_TABLE
WHERE SOME_STUFF_IS_GOING_ON)

SELECT GEND "Gender", 'Attribute 1'  "Attribute", SUM(UNITS) "Units", SUM(VAL) "Value", SUM(MARGIN) "Margin"
FROM SOME_CTE
WHERE PRODUCT IN ('12345', '23456', '34567', '45678')
GROUP BY GEND

UNION ALL

SELECT GEND, 'Attribute 2'  ATTR_NAME, SUM(UNITS), SUM(VAL), SUM(MARGIN)
FROM SOME_CTE
WHERE PRODUCT IN ('01234', '02345', '03456', '03567')
GROUP BY GEND
ORDER BY "Gender", "Attribute"
```

...and so on.

As you can see, with 2 attribute groups containing 4 products each there is no problem, but when we get to about 30 with several hundred each, it could be too long.

**Note: I have tried things like shortening field references in the repeated parts of the query string to 1 character etc. which helps but does not solve the problem.**
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround is to send multiple queries. Since you are using `union all`, you could execute every time single `select` statement, i.e.

create table in (for example) master database (don't create temporary tables! as they will be dropped after every query) - but before that, make sure you create new table, so delete old one if exists (also drop the table after you are done with it). Now every single `select` statement you'll change to `insert` statement, which will insert records to your so-called temporary table.

This way, you'll avoid lengthy queries, you'll just send single `insert .. into.. select` statements.

At the end, to get all results, you just need simple `select` query. After getting this data, you should drop that table, as it's no longer needed.